# df['column1'] != df['column2'] number that appear to match show up, why?

Tags: pandas, comparison

So I am trying to compare a recalculated field to an existing field in a table in pandas, to identify differences. When I look for values that don't agree, it returns values that appear to agree.

Why is this happening?

[image]

Updated with data types

[image]

Just a note, I was able to fix it by apply round to my calculation, but I'm still really interested if anyone knows why this happens. Definately not what I would expect. Also note that about half of my rows did match and didn't display in the results.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some data and how your expected output should look like. It will be helpful for us to provide you solutions.

Comment: So the data came from an excel file that had the columns "Gross_Pay", "Net_Pay", and "Tax_Amount". I pulled it into pandas. I then created a new column to recalculate Net_Pay. So I calculated Gross_Pay minus Tax_Amount. This should match Net_Pay, and it visually looks like it does and it does in excel, but doesn't here and I don't know why.

Comment: maybe the dtypes of the columns are different.

Comment: Updated, data types look the same